# What to use if there is no file 'org.semanticweb.HermiT.Reasoner.ReasonerFactory'?

Tags: java, owl, ontology, owl-api

I downloaded Hermit OWL Reasoner, but there is no file 'org.semanticweb.HermiT.ReasonerFactory', please tell me from where i can take this class.

Answer (score 0):

Your question title refers to a different class name than your question. The class name in the title is from HermiT 1.3.8 or earlier, the name in the question is from the net.sourceforge.owlapi fork (most recent release 1.4.3). Which version have you downloaded?

Comment: I downloaded HermiT 1.3.8 by this link http://www.hermit-reasoner.com/download.html. 
But I just started to learn this technology and in all examples ReasonerFactory is connected, where can I get version 1.4.3?

Comment: All OWLAPI managed releases of HermiT are available on Maven Central. https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:net.sourceforge.owlapi%20AND%20a:org.semanticweb.hermit&core=gav